# Transfer files from PC to Android mobile/Tablet wirelessly

Tags: wireless-networking, android

I need to wirelessly transfer some real-time date from my desktop application to an android mobile/tablet.

I think that I will have to develop my own application for that but I am wondering which technology can help me to do so.

Mainly, I am looking for wi-fi direct technology to implement the functionality of automatic transferring of real-time data from PC to mobile. My question is, is it really possible to do that with "wi-fi direct" or is there any other method?

Basic idea

- Make your PC a Wi-Fi hotspot.
- Connect your mobile to the PC's wi-fi hotspot
- As soon as a mobile client is connected to the PC wi-fi hotspot server, the PC starts sending the data (i.e. image) to the client.

Comment: How about `adb push`? ADB can connect wirelessly over Wi-Fi.

Comment: @gronostaj: Thanks for the suggestion. I will have a look into it. Btw the video at this line { https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LRYmcb0ZPk } is absolutely what I need (instead of mirroring the complete desktop, I want to send only a single image and some other test data).